# Must a house be cleaned for Pesach even if a seder won't be held there?

Tags: passover

I'm trying to understand how the holiness codes in Leviticus and Deuteronomy apply to people versus places. It is written, "all shall keep your laws" and "all shall post the laws at their gates", so presumably every Jewish family must celebrate Passover, but does that mean every family must do so at least once at their own individual dwelling every year?  It doesn't seem sensible that every family must celebrate Pesach in their own homes since that's why people attend synagogue seders.  If a family attends seder other than their own house, must they clean their house as if they are celebrating Passover there anyway?

Comment: You should read [Exodus chapter 12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0212.htm), particularly verses 4 46 and 19

Answer (score 1):

A Jew is prohibited from owning *Hamez* over the seven days of *Pesah*. If a Jew didn't nullify (or destroy or sell) his or her *Hamez* before *Pesah* and returns home to see his or her own *Hamez*, s/he has transgressed at least one Torah prohibition.

Therefore, one must nullify one's *Hamez* before *Pesah* irrespective of if s/he may not be at home at all during the holiday of *Pesah* since, in the event one does enter one's home during *Pesah*, s/he will transgress a Torah prohibition.

Comment: Please check that my edit matches your intent.

Comment: "and returns home to see his or her own _Hamez_", "in the event one does enter one's home during _Pesah_": isn't there a divinely-imposed prohibition even if it's not seen?

Comment: Also, you may wish to clarify what you mean by "nullify". I doubt it's clear to people not already familiar with it in this context.

Comment: @msh210 Destroying it would certainly fulfill all obligations (Biblical and Rabbinic); but, "nullifying" in one's heart fulfills one's Biblical obligation. HaZa"L decreed that one also destroy it to prevent one from negating the nullification in one's heart (e.g. if one sees a really tasty piece of cake), which would then revert one to transgressing a Biblical (vs. "only" a Rabbinic) prohibition. That's why I left it vague as it's an interesting question if nullification in one's heart would suffice for one who won't return home during the entire holiday (maybe a case of Sefeq Sefe'iqa?).

Comment: @msh210 I wrote this answer hurriedly. In truth, addressing Biblical and Rabbinic obligations and including sources for everything is in order.

Comment: @Lee Mideoraita you could choose to destroy everything and not nullify it. They are both ways of ridding oneself of ownership.